# ¿Por que aparece "undefined" pegado al valor de la variable?

Tags: javascript, undefined

estoy practicando y me ha pasado esto por primera vez.
Cuando termina el bucle, se añade *undefined* pegado a la variable, alguien puede explicarme por que sucede eso, y como se puede solucionar?

---

```js
let frase2 = Array.from("Papagallo, Muercielago, Pepe.");
let frase3 = ""

for (let i = 0; i <= frase2.length; i++){
    if (frase2[i] == "a"){
        frase3 += frase2[i]+"p"+frase2[i];
    } else if (frase2[i] == "e"){
        frase3 += frase2[i]+"p"+frase2[i];
    } else if (frase2[i] == "i"){
        frase3 += frase2[i]+"p"+frase2[i];
    } else if (frase2[i] == "o"){
        frase3 += frase2[i]+"p"+frase2[i];
    } else if (frase2[i] == "u"){
        frase3 += frase2[i]+"p"+frase2[i];
    } else {
        frase3 += frase2[i];
    }
} 
console.log(frase3);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto es porque los arrays tienen índice cero y cuando haces `frase2[lenght]` debido al `for` que tiene como condición `i <= frase2.length` estás accediendo un elemento no definido que está fuera de tu `string`. Debes de definir el condicional en tu `for` como:

```
i < frase2.length
```

En otras palaras, el primer elemento de `frase2` es `frase2[0]` y el último es `frase2[frase2.length-1]`, porque el índice cero cuenta como un elemento .

```js
let frase2 = Array.from("Papagallo, Muercielago, Pepe.");
let frase3 = ""

for (let i = 0; i < frase2.length; i++) {
  if (frase2[i] == "a") {
    frase3 += frase2[i] + "p" + frase2[i];
  } else if (frase2[i] == "e") {
    frase3 += frase2[i] + "p" + frase2[i];
  } else if (frase2[i] == "i") {
    frase3 += frase2[i] + "p" + frase2[i];
  } else if (frase2[i] == "o") {
    frase3 += frase2[i] + "p" + frase2[i];
  } else if (frase2[i] == "u") {
    frase3 += frase2[i] + "p" + frase2[i];
  } else {
    frase3 += frase2[i];
  }
}
console.log(frase3);
```

Comment: Ohhh!! Es cierto! llevo un buen rato buscando y releyendo y no encontraba la solución! Esta claro que el saber es poder jeje muchas gracias por la ayuda y por contestar tan rápido! :D